# How to incorporate multiple .pem certification files to a single .pfx file?

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate, openssl, private-key

I'm working on IIS on Windows 2019. I have given certificate files; cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem and privkey.pem. I believe that I have to convert this to .pfx to incorporate it to the IIS. How to convert so that all 4 PEM files are included in a single PFX file? Please excuse me for the lack of knowledge in this area. I'm very very new to this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure you need both `chain.pem` and `fullchain.pem`?

Comment: Don't convert manually – use an ACME client that has direct IIS support; there are several of those.

Comment: Romeo Ninov no.. I absolutely have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `openssl` software you can try something like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out full_cert.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in name.pem -certfile fullchain.pem
```

This should generate `full_cert.pfx` file with private key, public key and full chain of intermediate certificates (from your CA)

The command below reflect the comment

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out full_cert.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in name.pem -certfile chain.pem
```

Comment: Certbot's fullchain.pem already includes the end certificate (i.e. fullchain.pem = cert.pem + chain.pem), so I guess the command could be simplified to load all certs from a single file?

Comment: @user1686, I see, let me add command which will be more appropriate

Comment: Thank you! in your first code, what is name.pem?

Comment: @guitarlass, it is `cert.pem`

Comment: `Specified logon session does not exist` i get this error after trying to bind the generated certificate. Any clue?

Comment: @guitarlass, no idea, sorry. Maybe will be better to create new question with this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I learned a new thing. regards